# Drop down menu in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created one page and added called list as main menu to it.

Afterwards, I created a second page and added that page as the child of the first page.  Now I want to show the second page in the menu link, in the form of a drop down. If I hover my mouse over the list, it displays list1 as sub. My problem is that I cannot get list1 into a Drupal variable.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish). If you want to change the order then create a new menu and select the item accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the replay but it does not work i added a superfish module enable it and i used the variable $superfish_menu in page.tpl.php and alseo define the regoin in my theme.info file but i get the blank array where i do wrong please help me

Comment: Once you install the module don't do any custom coding. 
Enable the module. Go to blocks section and enable the superfish block. In the configure you will have options to select the menu of your choice.